# clickable table row can't get data to a popup window

Tags: php, javascript, html

I would just wanted to ask for a better idea for this. the scenario is this:
1. Display messages on a clickable table row. if the message is already read the row can't be clicked
2. Onced clicked it will open a popup window used for replying to the message. when the window is closed the page should refresh.

The problem is I can only get the last row data. it seems session variables are overwritten.

```
    <?php
    //Display Messages Starts Here
    $msg = "SELECT * FROM messages WHERE sid=". $_SESSION['SESS_SERVICE_ID'] ."";
    $resulta = mysql_query($msg)or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resulta))
    {
        if($row['status']=='deleted'){
            echo "<tr bgcolor=#AAAAAA>";
            echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['stamp'])) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['msisdn'] . "</td>";
            echo "<td width=100%>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        else{
            // id like to use this to a popup form for reply
            echo "<tr onmouseover='ChangeColor(this, true);' 
                      onmouseout='ChangeColor(this, false);' 
                      onclick=\"DoNav();\">";
            echo "<td>" . date("Y-m-d",strtotime($row['stamp'])) . "</td>";
            echo "<td>" . $row['msisdn'] . "</td>";
            $_SESSION['SESS_MSG_ID'] = $row['id'];
            $_SESSION['SESS_MSG_DATA'] = $row['data'];
            echo "<td width=100%>" . $row['data'] . "</td>";
            $_SESSION['SESS_MSG_NUM'] = $row['msisdn'];
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are setting a `$_SESSION` variable, and this one is overwritten every time.

You better store it in an array, like:

```
$_SESSION[$row['id']]['SESS_MSG_DATA'] = $row['data'];
```

And then change the onClick to:

```
onclick=\"DoNav(".$row['id'].");
```

And of course in DoNav function:

```
function DoNav(row_id){
    window.open( "reply.php?id="+row_id, "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 555, resizable = 0" );
}
```

And then in reply.php, get the ID with `$_GET['id'];` and get the data from the session like this:

```
$_SESSION[$_GET['id']]['SESS_MSG_DATA'];
```

Besides the SESS_MSG_DATA you can store them all in this array:

```
$_SESSION[$row['id']][ANY VARIABLE HERE]
```

Comment: I did what you suggest and its not overwritting it now but the popup window still dont get the data needed. still having Undefined variable for it

Comment: how do you read the data there? How do you pass the variable to the popup? And what does function DoNav() do

Comment: `function DoNav(row_id)
  {
  window.open( "reply.php", "myWindow", "status = 1, height = 300, width = 555, resizable = 0" )
  }`

Comment: I changed my answer. Note I also turned around the array, which makes more sense now :)